typescript doesn't infer type of value for a key
what's wrong with the way I define this type
type Payload<Es> = {
  trigger:
    Es extends Record<infer K, infer V>
     ? { key: K, data: V } : never
}

type Evs = {
  "item.1": { ok: "Y", code: number }
  "item.2": 1 | 0
}
const payload: Payload<Evs> = {
  trigger: {
    key: "item.1",
    data: 1
  }
}


payload.trigger.data doesn't get inferred as I expect
expected
{ ok: "Y", code: number }
what I get
0 | { ok: "Y", code: number } | 1

Record<K, V> doesn't associate a particular key with a particular value.  If you infer to Record you'll mix the values together. You don't want infer at all, but a distributive object type as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

thanks a lot, that's exactly what I wanted, I was doing it all the way wrong

The Record<K, V> utility type is a type corresponding to objects with property keys of type K and property values of type V. But specific keys are not associate with specific values.  If you start with {a: string, b: number} and try to infer a Record<K, V> from it, you'll get Record<"a" | "b", string | number>. That's the same type you'd get from {a: number, b: string}.  So you really don't want to infer to a Record at all here, unless you want to mix all the properties together.
Instead you really need to just map over the type, iterating over each key K, and producing the corresponding object type, and then index into the mapped type to get a union of properties. That is, you want a distributive object type (as coined in microsoft/TypeScript#47109):
type Payload<E> = {
  trigger: { [K in keyof E]: { key: K, data: E[K] } }[keyof E]
}

You can verify that this gives you what you're looking for:
type Evs = {
  "item.1": { ok: "Y", code: number }
  "item.2": 1 | 0
}

type PEvs = Payload<Evs>;
/* type PEvs = {
    trigger: {
        key: "item.1";
        data: {
            ok: "Y";
            code: number;
        };
    } | {
        key: "item.2";
        data: 0 | 1;
    };
} */

const payload: Payload<Evs> = {
  trigger: {
    key: "item.1",
    data: 1 // error!
  }
}

Playground link to code

Hi, in your code the typescript will infer the ok property as string not Y.

There's no "inferring" that I see anywhere. Show me what you mean, with actual code.

The format you've written will cause TypeScript to infer a union of all possible values for Record, which will make it impossible for TypeScript inference to match your expected type. Unless you provide another generic type to its Payload type that specifies which value type you want for the data based on special key. So:

type Payload<Es, P extends keyof Es = keyof Es> = {
    trigger: Es extends Record<infer K, infer V> ? { key: K, data: Es[P] } : never
}
type Evs = {
    "item.1": { ok: "Y", code: number };
    "item.2": 1 | 0;
};

const payload: Payload<Evs, 'item.1'> = {
    trigger: {
        key: "item.2",
        data: { ok: "Y", code: 123 } // TypeScript will infer { ok: "Y", code: number }
    }
};


